# How do I split up Python Tkinter code in multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first post here!

First here's the github link (I'm noob on github too) of my [project](https://github.com/Banadora/Learning-python).

Edited:

So here is a example of what I want to do, I have a big Tkinter class with frames,labels,menus,buttons and all and some functions in it too.

I want to let the UI description in my MakeUI() and move my funcs to another file, but I need to still have access to widgets.

< Main.py >

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
from Interface import *


Fenetre = Tk()
UI = MakeUI(Fenetre)

UI.mainloop()

UI.destroy()
```

< Interface.py >

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *


class MakeUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, Fenetre, **kwargs):

        # Héritage
        Frame.__init__(self, Fenetre, width=1500, height=700, **kwargs)

        self.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.FrameInfos = LabelFrame(self, text="Choix des paramètres", padx=2, pady=2)
        self.FrameInfos.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=5, pady=5)

        self.MsgInfosCarte = Label(self.FrameInfos, text="Example", width=45)
        self.MsgInfosCarte.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

    def AfficherCarte(self):
        self.MsgInfosCarte["text"] = "OK"
```

And now in this example, I need to move the AfficherCarte function to another file like MapFuncs.py or else.
And I want MakeUI to be able to call other files funcs and other files funcs to modify the interface.

I can't manage to do it properly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on how to split up the big `MakeUI` class?

Comment: Yeah exactly !
Like creating a MapFuncs.py with Map functions like the last one AfficherCarte.

Comment: Please revise your post so there is an actual question.  You will want to put the specific code you are asking about into the question, don't just link to a repository. Be specific as to what you want help with.

Comment: Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You probably only need a dozen or so lines of code split between two files to illustrate the general problem of how to split tkinter code across files.

Comment: Edited, I hope it's OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to move a function modifying a widget of your GUI in a separate file, you could simply pass the **widget** instance (or an object in which this instance is stored) as an **input argument** of your function:

< MapFuncs.py >

```
def AfficherCarte(UI):
    UI.MsgInfosCarte["text"] = "OK"
```

< Interface.py >

```
import tkinter as tk
from MapFuncs import AfficherCarte

class MakeUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, Fenetre, **kwargs):

        # Héritage
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, Fenetre, width=1500, height=700, **kwargs)
        self.pack()

        self.FrameInfos = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Choix des paramètres", padx=2, pady=2)
        self.FrameInfos.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=5, pady=5)

        self.MsgInfosCarte = tk.Label(self.FrameInfos, text="Example", width=45)
        self.MsgInfosCarte.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

        # Call function from external file to modify the GUI
        AfficherCarte(self)
```

If you're doing this because your code is getting too large, another way would be to divide your GUI into separate classes for each major part of the interface (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/4084269).